# show a trajectory of a projectile by position vector and velocity vector

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics

We are so motivated to show the projectile motion but emphasize to **vector algebra**. We could find some help in SE for the projectile motion but non of them have been satisfied our aims. Please see the bellow equation for the position and velocity vectors:

```
r[t_] := 
  ( v0 Cos[α] t + x0) i +
   0.5 a t^2 + v0 Sin[α] t + y0) j; 
v[t_] := 
  ( v0 Cos[α]) i + (0.5a t + v0 Sin[α] t) j
```

in which the arbitrary parameters (`a<0, v0, α, x0, y0`) can be defined before running. In an explicit format

[image]

The parabolic shape of the projectile can be given by:

```
y[x_] := 
  (a x^2)/(2 v0^2 Cos[α]^2) + x Tan[α] + y0
```

Firstly we wish to have a figure **containing the position and velocity vector as functions of time** and should be animated by `Manipulate` function. Same as:

[image]

Secondly, it is very interesting to have the approximate velocity obtained from `Δr/ϵ`, in which `ϵ` can be changeable, and the real velocity for getting better comparison between them. They are plotted in the bellow figure

[image]

Comment: Your equations of motion look wrong to me. Your equation for `r` has unbalanced parentheses and gravity seems to be acting in the positive x direction rather than in the negative y direction.

Comment: So sorry I will correct that.

Comment: You might find the following demonstration useful: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/2DKinematicsOnAFigureEightCurve/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping it simple...

Define parameters

```
a = -10; v0 = 5; α = Pi/4; x0 = 0; y0 = 3;
```

Express position and velocity explicitly as vectors using `List`

```
r[t_] := {v0 Cos[α] t + x0, 0.5 a t^2 + v0 Sin[α] t + y0}
v[t_] := {v0 Cos[α], a t + v0 Sin[α]}
```

Plot the trajectory

```
traj = ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

Define functions to display arrows

```
rvec[t_] := Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[t]}]
vvec[t_, ϵ_] := Arrow[{r[t], r[t] + ϵ v[t]}]
avec[t_, ϵ_] := Arrow[{r[t], r[t + ϵ]}]
```

Show all the graphics and Manipulate t, ϵ

```
Manipulate[Show[traj, Graphics[{Thick,
    Red, rvec[t], rvec[t + ϵ], Blue, vvec[t, ϵ], Darker[Green], avec[t, ϵ]}]],
 {t, 0, 1.2}, {ϵ, 0.01, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, and likely instructive, to generate the equations from a more general starting point. The following is not yet completely general due to the assumption of constant accelerations `ax` and `ay`, but further generalization is easily implemented. Also, you can just [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) to recover the explicit formulas if you wish.

```
eqnDefs = {
r''[t] == {ax, ay},
r'[0] == {v0 Cos[0], v0 Sin[0]},
r[0] == {x0, y0}
} 
/. {ax -> 0, ay -> -9.81, v0 -> 20, 0 -> π/3, x0 -> 0, y0 -> 0}
```

Then you just numerically solve the differential equations with [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

```
soln = First@NDSolve[
eqnDefs,
{r},
{t, 0, 10}
]
```

Finally, you use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) to show the trajectory and [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) to generate the vector depictions using [`Arrow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html).

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[r[tt] /. soln],
    {tt, 0, 4},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.3], Gray]
    ],
   Graphics[
    {Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[t] /. soln}],
     Red, 
     Arrow[{r[t] /. soln, 
       Evaluate[r[t] /. soln ] + Evaluate[ r'[t] /. soln]/2}]
     }]    
   }],
 {{t, 2}, 0, 4}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of issues. The equations are not correct (they are dimensionally inconsistent). In the following the acceleration is taken as 9.8 $\text{m}\cdot\text{s}^{-2}$:

Simple equation of motion:

```
r[v0_, a_, y0_, t_] := {0, -4.9 t^2} + v0 t {Cos[a], Sin[a]} + {0, y0}
```

Calculating time and x position that $y(t)=0$:

```
hit[v0_, a_, y0_] := 
  Quiet[{u, x} /. 
    Solve[r[v0, a, y0, u] == {x, 0} && u > 0, {u, x}][[1]]];
```

Calculate peak of trajectory:

```
pk[v0_, a_, y0_] := 
  r[v0, a, y0, t] /. 
   Quiet[Solve[D[r[v0, a, y0, t], t][[2]] == 0, {x, t}][[1]]];
```

A function to allow visualization:

```
func[v0_, a_, y0_, p_] := Module[{xh, th, peak = pk[v0, a, y0][[2]]},
  {th, xh} = hit[v0, a, y0];
  ParametricPlot[r[v0, a, y0, t], {t, 0, th}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1 xh}, {0, 1.1 peak}}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[r[v0, a, y0, p th]]}, 
   Frame -> True]]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 func[v0, a, y0, p], {v0, 2, 10}, {{a, 1}, 0.1, Pi/2}, {y0, 0.1, 
  1}, {p, 0, 1, Animator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I wish the vectors (position and velocity) be shown on the plot.

Comment: @Irreversible you could adapt or modify to achieve your desired aim.I suggest you look at the documentation, your own code and play. Good luck :)